# Making OCaml's Garbage Collector more predictable

Tags: memory, memory-management, garbage-collection, ocaml

I have developed a certain tool using OCaml (which was extracted from Coq proofs). I want to do some experiments to empirically observe the memory consumption by this OCaml program.

However, OCaml is a garbage collected language and this makes its behavior of memory consumption somewhat unpredictable and also hard to explain. I would like to somehow tune the garbage collector so that it behaves in a more predictable, preferably eager, fashion.

Is there some way to best tune the Garbage Collector to my needs? For example, is it possible to plugin a different garbage collector into OCaml? Perhaps a more eager one, or something which uses a different mechanism, like reference counting.

One of the solutions I have found so far is to manually trigger the Garbage Collector by using `Gc.minor ()` and `Gc.major ()` from the `Gc` module. I'd appreciate other suggestions.